# using scp or echo in zsh with alias parameter print 'No such file or directory'

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, scp, parameters

here zsh on MacOSX.

I would like to point out that I have tried several ways, with and without quoting, single or double quoting, with and without brackets, with/out $variables. But I receive ever this 'No such file or directory'.

There is a line of my ~/.zshrc file aliases section.

`alias cpsos='source="${1}"; destination="${2}"; scp -i ~/.ssh/id_sos "${source}" __USERNAME__@__SERVER__:"${destination}"'`

When in Terminal I use

```
% cpsos "/Users/sos/dev/g/qrcode/net.png" "/home/sos/webapps/demo/frontend/static/"
```

I receive
`/home/sos/webapps/demo/frontend/static/: No such file or directory`

I've also try a simply echo to do some debug and understand what's the error, using either some trick.
Here some another ~/.zshrc lines

```
# Automatically quote globs in URL and remote references
__remote_commands=(scp rsync)
autoload -U url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
zstyle -e :urlglobber url-other-schema '[[ $__remote_commands[(i)$words[1]] -le ${#__remote_commands} ]] && reply=("*") || reply=(http https ftp)'
alias scp='noglob scp'
alias echosos='source="${1}"; destination="${2}"; echo "Source: ${source}" ; sleep 1; echo "Destination: ${destination}";'
```

Then, on Terminal

```
% echosos "/Users/sos/dev/g/qrcode/net.png" "/home/sos/webapps/demo/frontend/static/"
```

Reply

`Source:  Destination:  zsh: permission denied: /Users/sos/dev/g/qrcode/net.png`

Obtaining always "No such file or directory" or "permission denied". What's happen?

Has anyone encountered this type of problem in the past and knows the reasons for this very annoying malfunction that forces you to give up on fully using the alias functionality?
In simple bashrc this didn't happen and I'm seriously thinking of returning to this shell as the default.

Thanks for your attention.